# Extrapolating dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Consider a vector $x \in\mathbb{R}^n$, where I know its projection in all other dimensions smaller than $n$. Can I find projection of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m > n$.

Please excuse me if I am not using right terminologies as I am not from mathematical background but I can try my best to elaborate my question if there is some ambiguity.

**EDIT**

As answered by @woofy, If I embed $m-n$ `0's` can I be sure it is the right projection? I mean consider $x' \in \mathbb{R}^l$ where $l < n$, and $x'$ is projection of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^l$ if I embed $n-l$ `0's` to $x'$ I will not always get $x$ right?

Okay I got it that there is no unique projection from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ if $m>n$. But can we somehow approximate the projection matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m{\times}n}$?

Consider I have $N$ vectors $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\forall i \in N$. And for example if I have list of projections in lower dimensions $l$ where $l<n$, means I have all projections matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{l{\times}n}$. Can I still not able to approximate the projection of the a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: If you have no bounds on $m$ you can make the projections any arbitrary subspace by enlarging the dimension sufficiently. Said another way you have so many choices in how to embed your space into higher dimensions that it gives you enough degrees of freedom to customize the projections. You can't even approximate it without additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $m>n$.

For example, $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{m-n})$ is in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: Please check the edited post.

Comment: @MuazUsmani There is no unique projection from $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$ if $m>n$.